# accesing Views created in Hive using HcatLoader in Pig

Tags: hive, apache-pig, hcatalog

I was just trying something in hive and HcatLoader in Pig. What I did is, created a view in Hive and then tried to load data by view I created into pig using HcatLoader. But it seems it is not working. I just wanted to confirm that is there any way to do this? I am getting following error when I tried to load view in pig using HcatLoader

events=Load 'ViewName' using org.apache.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader();
dump events;

When I use any tableName instead of View from Hive, it seems to work. Further it does not give metastore error. As it says successfully connected to metastore at load statement when it comes to dump, it crashes with the following error.

Any Pointers will be helpful.

Thanks,
Atul

```
org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.FrontendException: ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias events
at org.apache.pig.PigServer.openIterator(PigServer.java:857)
at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.processDump(GruntParser.java:682)
at org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.parse(PigScriptParser.java:303)
at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:189)
at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:165)
at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.exec(Grunt.java:84)
at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:555)
at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:111)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:156)
Caused by: org.apache.pig.PigException: ERROR 1002: Unable to store alias events
at org.apache.pig.PigServer.storeEx(PigServer.java:956)
at org.apache.pig.PigServer.store(PigServer.java:919)
at org.apache.pig.PigServer.openIterator(PigServer.java:832)
... 12 more
Caused by: org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobCreationException: ERROR 2017: Internal error creating job configuration.
at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler.getJob(JobControlCompiler.java:731)
at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler.compile(JobControlCompiler.java:259)
at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher.launchPig(MapReduceLauncher.java:180)
at org.apache.pig.PigServer.launchPlan(PigServer.java:1270)
at org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeCompiledLogicalPlan(PigServer.java:1255)
at org.apache.pig.PigServer.storeEx(PigServer.java:952)
```

Comment: For people who found this post when looking for [ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34495085/error-1066-unable-to-open-iterator-for-alias-in-pig-generic-solution) here is a [generic solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34495086/983722).

Answer (score 3):

Response I recieved by posting it on some other forum.

"**HCatLoader does not support reading views in Hive**.  The issue is that a view is defined as a query on a table **(create view V as select x, y from t)**.

> Pig doesn't speak SQL,

and

> HCat doesn't contain Hive's execution engine

so it cannot execute the query either.  Reading Hive views from Pig and MR will require much tighter integration of the products than we currently have."

Comment: even i was facing the same issue and finally concluded, Pig can not read views using HCatLoader.

Answer (score 1):

I found the same issue the hard way today. Hive cannot read Hive Views (but lacks good exception handling code on this topic).
For the records (anybody else falling into this problem), this is how the current version behaves: On Hortonworks 2.3 with Pig 1.15 I only got the following error in the log:

> ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 2017: Internal error
>   creating job configuration.

Pig fails this way because there is no file to load (as we attempted to load from a View).

Answer (score -1):

Since Pig loads the data from a file in hadoop, reading data from an view (which does not have a physical file) may not work. 
May be if we can manage to create a file for the view in hadoop, Pig may be able to load it. Atleast a virtual pointer file to the actual data file.
Not sure if this is possible or has been thought through.

Comment: HCatLoader doesn't pick data from file, it uses Hive. If you want to clear it more you can try one thing. some time a data file contains null values which is automatically converted into '\N', which you can see in select statement. If you load the same data in pig script using HCatLoader, you will get values '\N' in dump statement.